# Saving a complex dictionary into a excel file

Tags: excel, pandas, dictionary

i have a problem with saving a complex dictionary into an excel file.

This is my code so far:

```
attention_relevance = model.get_attention(test)
attentionres = []
for key in attention_relevance.keys():
     attentionres.append(attention_relevance[key])
dfattention = pd.DataFrame(attentionres)
dfattention.to_excel(r'/savepath/attention.xlsx', index = False)
```

The dictionary i would like to save is called "attention_relevance".
The code is running without any error messages, but in the excel-file some of the values are not written, instead they are replaced by "...".
Like this:
[[[0.02923768 0.02157122 0.02464608 ... 0.06667057 0.03331407 0.0075733 ].
How can I fix this? I need all the values in there.
Anyone who can help?

Thank you very much!
Hinnerk8

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be saving a list in a list, not a dictionary or just 1 list.

or you can try

```
np.squeeze(attentionres)
```

and then save the file it would also work

Comment: Thanks for your response - I added the np.squeeze, but it does not solve the problem. Are there any other ideas?

Comment: oh. I am sorry. I couldnt find any other.